How to be ensure each table column occupies 25% width even with fewer columns
In my previous question, I asked about keeping 4 columns in view, even if there are more than 4 columns.
@G-Cyrillus provided a solution using the cqw unit, which works well. However, I face an issue when I have only two columns. I want these two columns to each occupy 25% of the width.
I tried using max-width with values of 25%, 25cqw, 200px, and also experimented with width: max(...) and width: min(...), but none of these approaches worked.
Is it possible to achieve this?
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <!-- <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <th>Column 5</th>
        <th>Column 6</th>
        <th>Column 7</th>
        <th>Column 8</th> -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <!-- <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td> -->
      </tr>
      <!-- More rows as needed -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Include border and padding in size calculations */
}

.table-container {
  max-width: 80vw;
  overflow: auto;
  container-type: inline-size;  /* Make it a container that you can query its size */
  border: solid;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  width: 25cqw;
  /* Each column occupies 25cqw (25% of the container's width) */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}


A <table> 's columns must occupy the <table> 100%. So if you want two columns that's 50% of .table-container then do this: table {width: 50%} th {width: 50%}.

Try this one for each column occupies 25%
HTML Code
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

CSS Code
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Include border and padding in size calculations */
}

.table-container {
  max-width: 80vw;
  overflow: auto;
  container-type: inline-size;  /* Make it a container that you can query its size */
  border: solid;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  width: 25%;
  /* Each column occupies 25% of the table's width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>


You could try using display grid:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Include border and padding in size calculations */
}

.table-container {
  max-width: 80vw;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 25%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner-cell {
  background-color: red;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.header{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="inner-cell">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="data">Data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-cell">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="data">Data</div>
  </div>
  <!--<div class="inner-cell">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="data">Data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-cell">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="data">Data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-cell">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="data">Data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-cell">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="data">Data</div>
  </div>-->
</div>



